# How to mass delete photos?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, storage, photos

I'm trying to free up some space on my phone so I uploaded my photos to OneDrive on my PC. I'd like to delete all my photos from Camera Roll now. Instead of checking each one to be deleted is there a function that I can use to delete them all at once? Seems very time consuming to delete one by one.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open photos app.
2. Open / Slide to albums tab.
3. Long press Camera Roll.
   [image: deleting Camera Roll photos]
4. Click delete contents.

Now all the contents in the Camera roll will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In **Windows Phone 8**:

1. Download [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj3pl), a file manager app from Microsoft.
2. Open the app and navigate to the camera roll folder.
3. In the app bar at the bottom, tap the "select" button.
4. Expand the app bar and tap on "select all files".
5. Tap the delete button and confirm.

In **Windows 10 Mobile**:

1. Launch the built-in File Explorer.
2. Navigate to the camera roll folder.
3. Expand the app bar and tap on "Select all".
4. Tap the delete button and confirm.

Comment: @Dawn No problem! If one of the answers here helped you, be sure to [mark it as accepted](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), for the benefit of others who might have the same problem.